# Parametrization of the Matérn Covariance Function

Tags: covariance, spatial, geostatistics

For geostatistics problems, I am used to working with the following parametrization for the Matérn covariance function.

For a stationary and isotropic Gaussian random field $X(\boldsymbol{s})$, $\boldsymbol{s} \in \mathbb{R}^d$, we have

\begin{align*}
\text{Cov}\left[X(\boldsymbol{s}_1), X(\boldsymbol{s}_2)\right] &= r(||h||), \text{ such that } ||h|| \text{ is the Euclidian distance between } \boldsymbol{s}_1 \text{ and } \boldsymbol{s}_2\\
&=\frac{\sigma^2}{2^{\nu - 1}\Gamma(\nu)} (\kappa \cdot ||h||)^{\nu} K_{\nu}(\kappa \cdot ||h||)
\end{align*}
where $K_{\nu}(\cdot)$ is a modified Bessel functions of the $2^{\text{nd}}$ order. Additionally,

- $r(0) = \sigma^2$ is the variance.
- $\nu > 0$ is the smoothness parameter (a Gaussian process with this covariance function is $\lceil\nu\rceil - 1$ differentiable).
- $\kappa > 0$ determines the practical correlation range; in particular, $\rho = \frac{\sqrt{8\nu}}{\kappa}$ is the distance at which the spatial correlation is close to $0.1$.

However, using the `RandomFields` in `R`, according to [its documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RandomFields/RandomFields.pdf) (p.337), the `RMmatern()` uses the following parameterizationn:
\begin{align*}
r(||h||) = \frac{1}{2^{\nu-1}\Gamma(\nu)}(\sqrt{2\nu}\cdot||h||)^{\nu}K_{\nu}(\sqrt{2\nu}\cdot||h||),
\end{align*}
where

- $\nu > 0$ is said to be the smoothness parameter (no problem here).

Moreover, the function has the following arguments `var`, `scale`, `...`.

Regarding this parametrization, I have two questions:

1. What does the `scale` parameter mean? How can I relate it to my original parameterization?
2. Is the parameter `var` the same as $\sigma^2$ in my original parameterization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a hyperlink in the explanation to the documentation for `RMmodel`, where `var` and `scale` parameters are explained.  If $r=\phi(h)$ is the correlation model, the covariance model is
$$C = \mathtt{var}\times\phi(h/\mathtt{scale})$$
That is, `var` is $\sigma^2$ and `scale` is $\sqrt{2\nu}/\kappa$

Comment: The general principle is OK but the expression for scale is ambiguous since it depends on the parameterisation, the OP having two parameterisations involving a parameter $\nu$. This is for the first parameterisation.